# CSS radius and hover fill entire area

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a tabbed navigation.

I can't get my hover color to fill the entire area of my tabs (rounded top left/right). Right now the hover only covers the linking text within the tab and the hover doesn't have rounded corners.

I want the hover to perfectly cover the area of the tabs - rounded corners and all.

HTML:

```
<div id="tabbed-widget-2" class="widget tabbed-widget">
    <div class="widget-wrap">
        <div class="tw-tabs ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
            <ul class="tw-tabbed-nav ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
                <li id="tab-link-2-0" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top">
                    <a href="#tw-content-2-0">Welcome</a>
                </li>
                <li id="tab-link-2-1" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top">
                    <a href="#tw-content-2-1">Topics</a>
                </li>
                <li id="tab-link-2-2" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top">
                    <a href="#tw-content-2-2">Archives</a>
                </li>
                <li id="tab-link-2-3" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active">
                    <a href="#tw-content-2-3">Social</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

CSS

```
#tab-link-2-0, #tab-link-2-1, #tab-link-2-2, #tab-link-2-3  {
        background: green;
        padding: 2px 12px;
        margin: 0 8px 0 0;
        -moz-border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
        border-top-left-radius: 8px;
        border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    }   

#tab-link-2-0 a:hover, #tab-link-2-1 a:hover, #tab-link-2-2 a:hover, #tab-link-2-3 a:hover {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffab35;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

green background is for li tag and you styled  :hover for a tag not li 
and `<a>` is an inline element add `display:block` to it 
http://tinkerbin.com/aqHTscEE

Comment: Remove the default bullet of li tag.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified Your code and it is working fine ::--

```
<div id="tabbed-widget-2" class="widget tabbed-widget">
    <div class="widget-wrap">
    <div class="tw-tabs ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <ul class="tw-tabbed-nav ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
    <li id="tab-link-2-0" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top">
    <a href="#tw-content-2-0">Welcome</a>
    </li>
    <li id="tab-link-2-1" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top">
    <a href="#tw-content-2-1">Topics</a>
    </li>
    <li id="tab-link-2-2" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top">
    <a href="#tw-content-2-2">Archives</a>
    </li>
    <li id="tab-link-2-3" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active">
    <a href="#tw-content-2-3">Social</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

CSS:--

```
#tab-link-2-0 a , #tab-link-2-1 a, #tab-link-2-2 a, #tab-link-2-3 a  {
        background: green;
        padding: 2px 12px;
        margin: 0 8px 0 0;
        -moz-border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
        border-top-left-radius: 8px;
        border-top-right-radius: 8px;
      display:block;
    }   

#tab-link-2-0 a:hover, #tab-link-2-1 a:hover, #tab-link-2-2 a:hover, #tab-link-2-3 a:hover {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffab35;
    }
```

Fiddle Link:--

http://jsfiddle.net/Cqf2R/3/

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `#tab-link-2-0 a:hover` to `#tab-link-2-0:hover`, etc. Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h5Ssh/). Also, here is some source code:

```
#tab-link-2-0:hover, #tab-link-2-1:hover, #tab-link-2-2:hover, #tab-link-2-3:hover {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffab35;
}​
```

And i'm not sure why the rounded corners are not showing for you, I'm using Chrome and i can see the rounded borders.