# css tab selected background color

Tags: css

based off code in my prior question: [CSS radius and hover fill entire area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11911894/css-radius-and-hover-fill-entire-area)

how do i get the tab that is selected to have the same background color of the visible box below? the rest of the tabs i want to remain the default color. this way the user knows which tab is selected very easily.

i see the `ui-state-default` `ui-corner-top` `ui-tabs-selected` `ui-state-active` classes but can't get the css right to make it work.

help?

Comment: what visible box below? we only had the code for your tabs.

Comment: not sure what to post be/c using widgets: www . livecrafteat . com /test/

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to highlight a tab on hover? I moved your background color into your class `.ui-state-default` and added a pseudo statement.

***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/GWgex/)*** is a working Live Demo. Is this you want?

Comment: not quite. that is the current hover i have. i want it to work so that if i select "welcome" or "social" that that tab then becomes that default orange while the other 3 are green. if i then select "topics" the topics tab changes to orange and the other default to green.

Comment: anyway to bump this question? i'm still stuck.

Comment: consider upvoting or accepting my answer if your problem is solved